# Decrease the upload/download speed

Tags: windows, macos

I am doing networking project, My current broadband internet speed is 2Mbps my application is working correctly. I need to test my application status 512Mbps or any other speed.

How to decrease the speed of internet, Is there any way to increase/decrease the speed by making changes in local machine.

Thanks.

Comment: This really isn't programming related. It should prob be on SuperUser.com

Comment: let your client application connect to localhost

Comment: sisis can you brief your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fiddler is a free alternative.  It's bandwidth limiter can break https in my experience.  Oh, and it only works with http connections.  But, free so...

Comment: I am using mac, is there is any free software for mac.

Answer (score 3):

http://netlimiter.com/ our perf team use this very successfully to simulate the real world comms situations. It costs but for a single seat its < 30 US